# Count foreign key in django

Tags: python, django

I am doing some statistics between products and suppliers in django 1.11 with python3, the problem is that I do not know how to relate the model:

```
class Proveedor(models.Model):
    nombre_empresa = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    direccion = models.TextField()
    telefono = models.IntegerField()
    fecha_registro = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre_empresa

class Producto(models.Model):
    nombre_producto = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    descripcion = models.TextField()
    precio = models.IntegerField()
    proveedor = models.ForeignKey(Proveedor)
    fecha_registro = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre_producto
```

With the following sql statement:

```
select nombre_empresa,count(prod.id_proveedor) from productos prod,proveedores prov where prod.id_proveedor=prov.id_proveedor group by nombre_empresa
```

My code :

```
from app.models import Producto,Proveedor

productos = Producto.objects.all() # How do I do the filter ?
for producto in productos:
    nombre_producto = producto.nombre_producto
    proveedor = len(producto.proveedor)
```

I need to see the name of the suppliers with the quantity products that each supplier

How can I make the same relation to load a list with that result?

Comment: I need to see the name of the suppliers with the quantity products that each supplier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the suppliers with the number of products of each of them you can use [`annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/)

```
sup_with_prod = Proveedor.objects.annotate(num_prod=Count('producto'))
```

and you can access the number of products like so:

```
sup_with_prod[0].num_prod
```

for the first supplier, and so on. Or, in your case:

```
for supplier in sup_with_prod:
    nr_products = supplier.num_prod
```

Comment: Thanks for the help doru.